# Load Meta detail with Model in one JSON request in Ember-data 1.13.8

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have the following route:

```
this.resource('users', { path: '/'});
```

And the following two ember models: **user** and **meta**

When I go to the above route and array of users is loaded using the overriden model function:

```
model: function() {
        return this.store.findAll('user');
    },
```

the server returns the following JSON:

```
{
  "users" : [ {
    "id" : "ab650b0d-bea7-4619-a3fd-95f4c7bfd722",
    "firstName" : "Shivam",
    "lastName" : "Sinha",
    "username" : "shiv",
    "gender" : "M",
    "contactdetails" : [ {
      "id" : "fb5c9345-037e-4a57-9801-2b260b9b15fa",
      "name" : "Shiv",
      "type" : "PRIMARY_EMAIL",
      "value" : "ssdfsdfa@outlook.com",
      "userExist" : true,
      "isVerified" : false
    } ]
  } ],
  "meta" : {
    "sort" : "id: ASC",
    "size" : 20,
    "number" : 0,
    "totalPages" : 1,
    "numberOfElements" : 1,
    "totalElements" : 1,
    "firstPage" : true,
    "lastPage" : true
  }
}
```

The user model gets properly deserialized and is loaded as an ember model. However meta model is ignored. How can I also get the meta model to load properly as an ember model without actually having to do a separate request ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your example it looks like you're trying to parse metadata instead of actually loading two models at once.

Take a look here for information on how to handle metadata:
http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.13.0/models/handling-metadata/

Based on your example you'll probably want to use something like this:

```
var meta = this.store.metadataFor("user");
```

Answer (score 0):

Credit @tbjers

There are two types of approach to this:

1. You can try slide loading:  http://guides.emberjs.com/v2.0.0/models/the-rest-adapter/#toc_sideloaded-relationships
2. However this is prob the best approach for meta details:

http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.13.0/models/handling-metadata/

OR with Ember 2:

http://guides.emberjs.com/v2.0.0/models/handling-metadata/

Since I am using ember 1.13.0 I used the following approach:

```
var meta = this.store.metadataFor("user");
```